# VBA - Find string in email body or subject

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to create a simple macro, which reads the *active* email and checks whether or not a certain string is present. Now, the string can have two possible formats, and will only contains digits.

**The two formats:**

`xxx-xxxxxxxx` or `xxxxxxxxxxx`
(x will always be a digit)

I am unsure on how to do this. Below I have a macro, which reads the mail - but it can only find a ***specific string***:

```
Sub AutomateReplyWithSearchString()

    Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim myObject As Object
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Dim mySelection As Word.Selection
    Dim strItem As String
    Dim strGreeting As String

    Set myInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set myObject = myInspector.CurrentItem

    'The active inspector is displaying a mail item.
    If myObject.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" And myInspector.IsWordMail = True Then
        Set myItem = myInspector.CurrentItem

        'Grab the body of the message using a Word Document object.
        Set myDoc = myInspector.WordEditor
        myDoc.Range.Find.ClearFormatting
        Set mySelection = myDoc.Application.Selection
        With mySelection.Find

            .Text = "xxx-xxxxxxxx"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchWildcards = True

        End With

        If mySelection.Find.Execute = True Then
            strItem = mySelection.Text

            'Mail item is in compose mode in the inspector
            If myItem.Sent = False Then
                strGreeting = "With reference to " + strItem
                myDoc.Range.InsertBefore (strGreeting)
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "There is no item number in this message."

        End If
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I think this sounds like ´RegEx´ might be useful. I'm not very skilled in it, otherwise i'd help out here.

Comment: Can there be longer strings that may contain those strings? E.g. xxxxxxxxxxxxx where x is a number? And then do you only want the first 11 or will therre always be a space after for example?

Comment: @QHarr The strings will always be 11 digits (with or without "-") example: 111-10001000 or 11110001000. I want to extract that string (with or without "-")

Comment: A basic regex to match those strings is (\d{11}|\d{3}-\d{8})   but if there are additional numbers immediately after these without a space, the part that matches will be selected from those strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex pattern:

```
(\d{11}|\d{3}-\d{8})
```

[Try it.](https://regex101.com/r/5YOJnG/1)

This example is copied from  [here](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/regex-parse-message-text/). I have not tested it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetValueUsingRegEx()
 ' Set reference to VB Script library
 ' Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Reg1 As RegExp
    Dim M1 As MatchCollection
    Dim M As Match

    Set olMail = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection(1)
   ' Debug.Print olMail.Body

    Set Reg1 = New RegExp

    With Reg1
        .Pattern = "(\d{11}|\d{3}-\d{8})"
        .Global = True
    End With
    If Reg1.test(olMail.body) Then

        Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(olMail.body)
        For Each M In M1
            Debug.Print M.SubMatches(1)

        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I can see that I use the `.find` in VBA. Can this use RegEx patterns?

Comment: @oliverbj NO. the [find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/items-find-method-outlook) method only use strings, that should be valid outlook **filters**. In your case a RegExp is more suited and this answer describe the only way to search for RegExep in the email body.... So +1